# How to get normal diff colors in Vim on verbose git commits?

Tags: git, vim, git-commit, git-diff

When running the normal `git diff` I get the intuitive colors that I'm used to:

[image: git diff output with red/green/white font color.]

Red for deleted, green for added, white for unchanged.

But when I run `git commit -v`, the included diff that opens in the editor has weird colors that I'm not used to, and so parsing the meaning of the diff is more difficult:

[image: git commit -v output with unhelpful colors.]

White/gray for deleted, cyan for added, white for unchanged? What is that?

What can I do so that the diff inside the editor on verbose commits has the same colors as when running `git diff` directly?

I am using MacOS and vim as editor (`git config --global core.editor /usr/bin/vim`)

Answer (score 4):

`git commit -v` opens a file named `COMMIT_EDITMSG`. Vim (8.2) will set the `filetype` of a file with this name to `gitcommit`.

The corresponding syntax rules (`$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/gitcommit.vim`) reference the `syntax/diff.vim` rules, which make the lines starting with `+` and `-` into `diffAdded` and `diffRemoved` syntax items, respectively.

You need to set up your colorscheme and/or terminal colors so that `diffAdded` looks green and `diffRemoved` looks red.

---

Check with `:hi diffAdded` and `:hi diffRemoved` why they are currently not green and red.

e.g. you may see

```vim
:hi diffAdded
diffAdded      xxx links to Identifier
```

and then

```vim
:hi Identifier
Identifier     xxx term=underline cterm=bold ctermfg=6 guifg=palegreen
```

---

To override the specific highlight groups relevant to verbose Git commits, one might add something like this to their `.vimrc`:

```vim
function! MyHighlights() abort
    highlight diffAdded ctermfg=2 guifg=#67c12c
    highlight diffRemoved ctermfg=1 guifg=#b82e19
endfunction
augroup MyColors
    autocmd!
    autocmd ColorScheme * call MyHighlights()
augroup END
```

If you don't already specify a `colorscheme`, you also need to add this to trigger the `ColorScheme` event:

```vim
colorscheme default
```

Comment: Relevant for next step: https://gist.github.com/romainl/379904f91fa40533175dfaec4c833f2f

Comment: Thanks, I get the same output for `diffAdded` and different values for `Identifier`. Could you please add to your answer also how to change the colors? In my case `$VIMRUNTIME` is not set so I don't see the files you mentioned.

Comment: See my comment for your next step, @talz.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Would you like to also edit the concrete steps into the answer for future readers, and then I'll accept the answer?